# Qt QNetworkConfigurationManager's onlineStatusChanged signal won't work in fresh Windows XP

Tags: qt, qtnetwork

My program that uses qtcored4.dll, qtguid4.dll and qtnetworkd4.dll works fine on my development computer that has qtcreator installed. I copy the executable and DLLs above as well as mingwm10.dll and libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll into a folder and when I copy it to a freshly installed windows xp, everything works fine except for QNetworkConfigurationManager's onlineStatusChanged signal?

Am I missing an DLL or is there another problem? I already used DependencyWalker to check the dependencies and only dependencies except for the DLLs above are kernel32.dll, ntdll.dll and msvcrt.dll which the fresh windows already has.

Comment: Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable (or SP1) missing?

Comment: One more thing: why do you copy Debug-time DLLs (see `d` at the end of filename before version number)? Also, reading [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-windows.html) won't hurt.